# Inconsistency in pandas Series range selection

Tags: pandas

Can someone explain the reason why int index is exclusive in the upper bound on a range select but a character indexing is inclusive.

```
num = pd.Series(np.arange(5), index=[0,1,2,3,4])

dic = pd.Series(np.arange(5), index=['0','1','2','3','4'])

num[0:4]

0    0 
1    1 
2    2 
3    3 
dtype: int64

dic['0':'4']

0    0
1    1
2    2
3    3
4    4
dtype: int64
```

I'm new to pandas but I'm thinking there might be some underlying reason for this seemingly strange behaviour that I'm hoping some of you can explain.

Comment: Try this: `dic[0:4]` ;-) I hope it will help you to understand the difference

Comment: I guess what you are saying is that when using integer values for your ranges you are querying some underlying index instead of the one specified explicitly in the index parameter in the Series object. This still does not explain the why symbolic indexing is inclusive as a default when the underlying is exclusive.

This also makes us not be able to define the index [10,111,12,44,1] and query the range num[10:1], since it would then try to use this underlying index instead of my defined index. But this is a separate problem.